# In a web application with Maven and Spring Boot, the controller does not return an HTML page

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, spring-mvc

The controller should return `index.html` file, but it doesn't return anything.
`localhost:8080` and `localhost:8080/home` open the White label Error Page.

All important files are listed below:

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>Practice14</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Practice14</name>
    <description>Practice14</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

The controller named HomePageController.java

```
package com.example.practice14.controller;


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomePageController {
    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home() {
        return "home_page";
    }
}
```

Here is the main class:

```
package com.example.practice14;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Practice14Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Practice14Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

The file structure:
[File Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJjTU.png)

White label Error Page для 'localhost:8080' и 'localhost:8080/home'

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dNW8Q.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ORaF.png)

I have gone through almost all the similar questions here in StackOverflow and tried all those but did not work in this case.

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: check your `application.properties`

Comment: That error page is going to be pretty important to know what it says to understand what's the problem.  Can you post what it shows?  You might also check `application.properties` or `application.yaml` for `server.contextPath=/somePrefix`.  If you have one then the URL the browser would use is `/somePrefix/home`

Comment: "application.properties' in my project is empty

Comment: Please do not add answers to the question body itself. Instead, you should add it as an answer. [Answering your own question is allowed and even encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Okay, I'll fix it. Thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution has been found. I recreated the project and the problem resolved itself. Most likely the problem was with the dependency `thymeleaf`.

Comment: please accept your answer so it is removed from the search for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0):

By default your project must have next structure:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── com
        │       └── example
        │           └── practice14
        │               ├── controller
        │               │   └── HomePageController.java
        │               └── Practice14Application.java
        └── resources
            └── templates
                ├── home_page.html
                └── index.html
```

Because **Spring Boot** by default use `classpath:/templates/` directory for **Thymeleaf templates**.

More details: [Common Application Properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html#application-properties.templating.spring.thymeleaf.prefix)

Comment: I have exactly the same project structure except that I have a missing file index.html